# Chrome Inline Install for extension not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to use the new chrome inline install feature for extensions (see here: http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/docs/inline_installation.html).

I can't get it to work unfortunately, and have very little clues to go by. I've added the link element to the head element

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pnnfemgpilpdaojpnkjdgfgbnnjojfik">
```

and I call

```
chrome.webstore.install();
```

in a jquery event handler. I've also verified my domain, however, I'm testing this on a local machine but have a subdomain pointed to my localhost (i.e. testing on dev.getbentobox.com which is mapped to localhost in my hosts file if that makes a difference).

When stepping through my js using the chrome debugger, chrome.webstore.install() is getting called and the function is defined. However, nothing happens - no install, no javascript exception, no console printing, nothing.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you try chrome.webstore.install(undefined, undefined, function(message) { console.log(message); })? The failure callback will have a reason why the install failed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your [Chrome Web Store item](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pnnfemgpilpdaojpnkjdgfgbnnjojfik) doesn't show the verified site. If you compare it to the ["We Heart It" extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iblenkmcolcdonmlfknbpbgjebabcoae), which can be inline installed from http://weheartit.com/heart-button, it has a green check saying "from weheartit.com". You'll need to edit your Web Store item, and associate your verified site with the item.

Answer (score 3):

As of December 2018 (Chrome version 71), Google has disabled this feature.  The workaround is to send the user to your extension in the Chrome Web Store.

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/inline_faq#change_dec18

> What will change in M71 (Dec 2018)?
>
> Beginning in M71, Chrome will no longer support the chrome.webstore.install() method and calling it will fail, resulting in a broken installation flow on your site. At this point calls to the API will throw a JavaScript TypeError. You should remove any calls to the API method before this date.

Comment: If you get a "chrome.webstore undefined" failure message this is why...