# Chrome extension inline install not working in verified IP site

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

1. I have verified my IP (not the domain) using webmasters tool and it successfully verified.
2. I have added `<link>` and called  chrome.webstore.install() and getting this error:

   `Inline installs can only be initiated for Chrome Web Store items that have one or more verified sites.`

I think I should call  chrome.webstore.install() from subdomain or a page. So I am calling from a page (index.html) but url is just the IP.(like http://52.1.165.721/#/home) (Angular UI routing and index is default page.)

My questions are:

1.I didn't have a domain yet. Is that a problem?

2.I have to install extension from home page itself. I got some websites (eg: https://adblockplus.org/) as examples. But don't know how to do that. Please help.

I went through

[How to test inline installation of Chromium/Chrome extensions locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908413/how-to-test-inline-installation-of-chromium-chrome-extensions-locally) ,
[Chrome Inline Install for extension not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572748/chrome-inline-install-for-extension-not-working?rq=1) and
[chrome.webstore.install(); Not working on verified site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521759/chrome-webstore-install-not-working-on-verified-site)

Comment: Did you add your supposedly verified domain to the web store item?

Comment: Yes. And I can see the Website link in the bottom right corner in the webstore.

Comment: See first screenshot in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29819272/934239) - did you do exactly that? Website link is different.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My bad I was verified site using my normal gmail account and uploaded extension using work gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Xan said I added Website link and didn't fill `Verify that this is an official item for a website you own:` because my domain was not listing there.

The problem was I uploaded extension using my work account and verified site using my personal account. So I added my other account as an owner with help of https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2454036?vid=1-635766230904751668-2044003462 and refresh list does the trick.

So I selected the  verified site from drodown and after a two minutes inline install worked.

Turns out:

1.We don't need to buy the domain. IP will work.

2.Calling chrome.webstore.install() from home page itself will work too. (Url doesn't matter I think)